# Printer Filter Failed error while printing files with long filename

Tags: command-line, printing, pdf, cups-lpd

Whenever I try to print the files with long name like

```
ACFrOgDqkhn2LRDLIxz0Zvdexu6R-mu4b0RDo5SRtmYs.pdf
```

it will not print but when I rename it to 1.pdf it will get printed.

On checking the `/var/log/cups/error` there is a line buffer overflow error. How to diagnose what's there error and how to remove it.

Edit1:
Using Ubuntu 16.04 on Kyocera Taskalfa 1800 printer, and cups version is 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.10. The problem is in this printer only other one which is epson working fine

Comment: Are your filenames longer than 255 characters? Please edit your question with details: Ubuntu version, Printer model, cups version (get from apt show cups), printer driver version.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 16.04 on Kyocera Taskalfa 1800 printer, and cups version is 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.10. The problem is in this printer only other one which is epson working fine.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your system details there, not in a comment. That way your question gets bumped back up to the front page for greater visibility. Thanks.